# Authentication Required message on Google Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, cookies

So i'm trying to extract some data using Google Script using API.

API document tells me to do it like this:

To Authenticate:

```
POST /safefleet/api/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: api.safefleet.eu
Content-Type: application/json
{"username": "test", "password": "1234"}
```

And then I get this response which is ok because I get it:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: sessionid=4ce508d20832d12a64fd49ecb336a7b6
{"message": "ok"}
```

After that I want to get the data that I need and it tells me to do it like this:

```
GET /safefleet/api/vehicles HTTP/1.1
Host: api.safefleet.eu
Cookie: sessionid=4ce508d20832d12a64fd49ecb336a7b6
```

And the answer that I should get should look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
[
    {"vehicle_id": 1234, "name": "Vehicle A", ...},
    {"vehicle_id": 2345, "name": "Vehicle B", ...}
    ...
]
```

But instead I get "Authentication Required"...

This is the code:

```
function Vehicles() {


  var LogIn = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://alpha.safefleet.eu/safefleet/api/authenticate/?username=test&password=123");

  Logger.log(LogIn.getHeaders()["Set-Cookie"]);

  var s = LogIn.getHeaders()["Set-Cookie"];

  var sessionid = JSON.stringify(s);

  var cookie = {
    "Cookie" : sessionid
  };
   var headers = {
    "Cookie": cookie
  };

  var params = {
    "method": "GET",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": headers
  };

  var Vehicles = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://alpha.safefleet.eu/safefleet/api/vehicles/", params);

  Logger.log(Vehicles);

}
```

Comment: The API documentation you provided requires the authentification request to be sent via POST, yet your code sends them via GET. Did you varify, that your authentification succeeds anyways?

Comment: Yes, my authentification succeeds, it gives me that cookie with the sessionid=..... so that's not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and see if this works.

```
function Vehicles() {

  var payload = {
    "username": "test",
    "password": "123"
  };

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'payload' : payload
  };

  var LogIn = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://alpha.safefleet.eu/safefleet/api/authenticate", options);

  var cookie = LogIn.getHeaders()["Set-Cookie"];

  var headers = {
    "Cookie": cookie
  };

  var params = {
    "method": "GET",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": headers
  };

  var Vehicles = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://alpha.safefleet.eu/safefleet/api/vehicles/", params);
  Logger.log(Vehicles);
}
```

Comment: Do you see the session ID in the log? For this `Logger.log(LogIn.getHeaders()["Set-Cookie"]);`?

Comment: Yes, when i do that it gives me the session id

Comment: The good news is that that bit is working fine But perhaps it may not be safe to post the session ID here. You said you tried putting the cookies the header but it did not work. Can you edit your original post and show what was the new script you tried?

Comment: Done! Can you please check to see if it is ok like this?